# Prevent elements with a classname "disabled" to move with Sortable.js

Tags: javascript, html, sortablejs

I have a list of items, which contains couple items with a class name `disabled`.

When dragging items, those "disabled" elements **should stay fixed** and **should not move** or **being pushed**.

What is the proper way to do it ?

```js
// List with handle
Sortable.create(listWithHandle, {
  handle: '.glyphicon-move',
  animation: 150,
  filter: ".disabled",
  onMove: function (evt) {
    return evt.related.className.indexOf('disabled') === -1;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  
  
  <!-- Latest Sortable -->
  <script src="https://raw.githack.com/SortableJS/Sortable/master/Sortable.js"></script>
  
  <div id="coolElement"></div>
  
  <!-- List with handle -->
  <div id="listWithHandle" class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item">
      <span class="badge">14</span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      Drag me by the handle
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item">
      <span class="badge">2</span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      You can also select text
    </div>
    <div class="disabled list-group-item">
      <span class="badge">1</span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      Should stay at index (2)
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item">
      <span class="badge">2</span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      You can also select text
    </div>
    <div class="disabled list-group-item">
      <span class="badge">1</span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      Should stay at index (4)
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item">
      <span class="badge">2</span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      You can also select text
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item">
      <span class="badge">2</span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      You can also select text
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item">
      <span class="badge">2</span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-move" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      You can also select text
    </div>
  </div>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what's the expected behaviour? let's say you have a non disabled element before and after a disabled element. You wouldn't be able to drag them either in such a case

Comment: yeah, everything should work as expected, able to be dragged around, except the disabled items. I will try to add more details to my "original question"

Comment: `Should stay at index (2)` - but _how_, if I move the `You can also select text` element further down ...? Then there _is_ only one more item before  `Should stay at index (2)`, so how _could_ it stay at index 2 then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that comes to mind is changing the default behaviour of sortable function.

Instead of making it possible to drag items around to insert them at a particular index, you could use a native swap plugin to make it so you swap items instead. This way there won't be any side effects of reordering list elements and you could keep your logic for disabling swaping the element and with the element.

```js
Sortable.create(list, {
  swap: true,
  swapClass: "highlight",
  animation: 150,
  filter: ".disabled",
  onMove: event => {
    return !event.related.classList.contains('disabled');
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: #f9c7c8 !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  
  
  <!-- Latest Sortable -->
  <script src="https://raw.githack.com/SortableJS/Sortable/master/Sortable.js"></script>

  
  <div id="list" class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item disabled">Item 1</div>
    <div class="list-group-item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="list-group-item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="list-group-item disabled">Item 4</div>
    <div class="list-group-item">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the reasonably the only way to do it with Sortablejs without actually changing its default behaviour.
Using swapping makes it work without real-time animations. thank you anyway.